How to set proxy proxy-server including username and password as options.AdditionalBrowserArguments ? in WebView2
How to set proxy proxy-server including username and password as options.AdditionalBrowserArguments  in WebView2 , c# winforms
Tried with this code , but its not working..
CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions();
options.AdditionalBrowserArguments = "--proxy-server=000.00.000.000:8080@username:password";


Where's your call to CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync and EnsureCoreWebView2Async

i know , but how ?
i can able to add proxy server and port but not with username and password
